# Authorizing .net webapi application with identityserver4

Tags: asp.net-web-api, identityserver4, identityserver3

I have identityserver4-based identity server
I have .net core api, which is successfully authorized using access_token from 
IS
but, non-core webapi returns unauthorized requests for controllers marked with Authorize attribute

API startup class:
     public class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {

```
        app.UseIdentityServerBearerTokenAuthentication(new IdentityServerBearerTokenAuthenticationOptions
        {
            Authority = "http://localhost:5000",
            ValidationMode = ValidationMode.Both,
           RequiredScopes = new[] { "ofd" },

        });


    }
}
```

what did I miss?

Answer (score 0):

```
<add key="owin:AutomaticStartup" value="true"/>
```

was missed in web.config/appSettings,
and owin middleware did not start